# Infinite loop while sorting a linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am new to C programming, and I have to sort my linked list. This linked list represents a polynomial which has been created by user's input. Each node has a coefficient and a power. When I try to sort the list and return it to the main function where I print it, nothing is printed (I think my program never exits a `while` loop).

Here I create the struct:

```
struct node
{
    int sunt;
    int dun;
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node* Poly;
```

Here is my code where I sort the list (`head` is my initial list's name):

```
struct node* poly = head;

struct node* temp;
int length = 0;

while (poly != NULL)
{
    length++;
    poly = poly->next;
}

poly = head;

while (length > 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((poly != NULL) && (poly->next != NULL))
    {
        if (poly->dun > poly->next->dun)
        {
            temp = poly;
            poly = poly->next;
            poly->next = temp;
            if(i = 0)
            {
                head = poly;
            }
            i ++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i = 0)
            {
                head = poly;
            }
            i ++;
        }
        poly = poly->next;
    }
    length --;
    poly = head;
}
return head;
```

And here is where I print the list in main function (POLYmake function is where I create and sort the list):

```
poly1 = POLYmake();

while(poly1 != NULL)
{
    printf("%d %d \n", poly1->sunt, poly1->dun);
    poly1 = poly1->next;
}
```

I know it's quite complicated, but I have no experience in C and I hope you could help me.

Comment: learn to use a debugger - it will make life much easier. You didnt say what platform you are on o I can give more specific advice

Comment: When poly is the last node of the list, poly->next is NULL. In this case I don't want to enter the while loop.

Comment: One of two things is happening here probably. First, how did you initialize or populate your `poly` structure? Did you make sure you set `next` elements to NULL for all new nodes? Second, inside the `if` of your inside `while`, you set `poly->next` to the previous setting of `poly` which, it it's happening a lot, seems it would just loop and never reach a NULL node. That's a superficial analysis as I don't know for sure that's going to happen, but you need to look at that carefully. The logic looks suspicious to me.

Comment: if(i = 0)
 will always set i to 0... it should be if(i ==0)

Comment: @JeffWatkins has the answer. Also you can factor `if (i==0) {head = poly} ; i++` out of each branch of the `if` condition (i.e. only write it once).

Comment: It still has the same problem, it is in an infinite loop although I changed if (i=0) to if (i==0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you break your linked list and form a loop in the inner loop's first if branch

```
temp = poly; // (1) 
poly = poly->next; // (2)
poly->next = temp; // (3)
```

Assume you have a list a -> b -> c -> ... and enter the if then poly points to a so will temp after (1). After (2) poly will point to b. The (3) statement will then assign the next pointer of b to temp, which is a.
This results in a cycle a -> b -> a -> b -> ... and you never reach c and therefore stay in the loop forever. You should set the next pointer of a to c if you swap a and b.

Edit: In addition the previous node (whose next pointer points to poly) has to be updated as well. To do so, the previous node can be kept in a separate `prev` pointer and `prev->next` can be set to that node that is first of the two after the swap.

Comment: I tried this:

   
 
                               `temp = poly;

    poly = poly->next;

    poly->next = temp;

    poly->next->next = temp->next;`
but it still is wrong. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think `struct node* next = poly->next->next; temp = poly; poly = poly->next; poly->next = temp; temp->next = next;` should work, but I did not verify it. And I did focus on the infinite loop produced by that error, there might still be some other problems as the others have already mentioned.

Comment: Why do we declare next?

Comment: Just storing the missing link somewhere (here `next`) and correctly setting it after the rest of the rotation is done seems to be the easiest way. You may be able to do it without an additional variable.

Comment: `temp = poly->next; poly->next = temp->next; temp->next = poly; poly = temp;` should be the same without an additional variable.

Comment: This is the only way that worked and sort the list BUT the last node of my list is missing

Comment: I tried a list with 5 nodes but the first and the last were not printed.

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing the actual code after you have made all the proposed changes. The absence of the first node can be caused if the head is not updated correctly in the cases where the first two nodes have to be swapped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94743/discussion-between-konstantina-papagiannopoulou-and-nh).

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
while(length > 0)
```

Will always be true, because when you finish going through your list, you only decrement it by one.

In addition, the following code:

```
if(i = 0)
{
    head = poly;
}
```

Should be

```
if(i == 0)
{
    head = poly;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a linked list bubble sort... I can see why this is the case, it still wouldn't be an infinite loop.

Comment: Each time OP goes through the outer loop, she decrements it by one, which seems to me to be correct. The problem is `if (i=0)` should be `if (i==0)` I think.

Comment: Exactly, I used the bubble sort. And yes the if conditional is incorrect!

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou I added that into my answer.

Comment: I don't think while(length > 0) is incorrect. I changed if (i=0) to if (i=0) but it still doesn't exit the loop

Comment: I mean....what have you tried? Place print statements in each loop so you can see which one is keeping control.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly...

```
if(i=0)
```

is wrong as it sets i

There's more though I think... you're setting the next nodes -> next to be the current one and vice versa, BUT, you're not setting the previous node's -> next OR the next node's->next as well, so you could well be creating a loop i.e. both of the next contain the same pointer. You need to tie up all the links in the list to do this and it's a pain!

so it should be:

```
node* prev = null

[...] ensure you set the prev after each iteration

then
node* swap1 = poly;
node* swap2 = poly->next;

swap1->next = swap2->next; (which you'd have to null check for beforehand)
swap2->next = swap1;
prev->next = swap2;
```

BUT: Conceptually, you're swapping entire links around just to swap some numbers. You could embed a struct pointer (which contain the ACTUAL values you're interested in) within the linkedlist entries and then swap those around rather than dynamically restructuring your list itself.

The moral of the story is, a linkedlist isn't the best structure for a bubble sort.

Comment: `   struct node* prev = NULL;
   if(poly->dun > poly->next->dun)
   {
    struct node* swap1 = poly;
    struct node* swap2 = poly->next;  
    swap1->next = swap2->next; 
    swap2->next = swap1;
    prev->next = swap2;
   }`

I tried this but now cmd closes when I run my program

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on this

```
temp = poly;
poly = poly->next;
poly->next = temp;
```

Presumably the idea is to swap two elements in the list.  So let's look at a list

```
item1 -> item2 -> item3 -> item4 -> NULL
```

Assume poly points at item2 and you need to swap it with item3. The first thing you do is set temp to poly, so both temp and poly point to item2.

```
item1 -> item2 -> item3 -> item4 -> NULL
         poly
         temp
```

Then you move poly to point at poly->next which is item3

```
item1 -> item2 -> item3 -> item4 -> NULL
                  poly
         temp
```

Then you set poly's next pointer to point at temp which is item2

```
             V------------
item1 -> item2 -> item3 -|  item4 -> NULL
                  poly
         temp
```

Note that now nothing points at item4. It's a memory leak. Note also that your list ends in a loop which means you'll never come across NULL and you'll never exit the inner loop.

---

How to solve this?

You'll notice that the item before poly is going to need to change its next pointer too, so you'll be needing a previous pointer. This is how i would do it

```
// Set up the loop before you start
struct node* previous = NULL;
poly = head;
while (poly != NULL && poly->next != NULL)
{
    if (poly->dun > poly->next->dun)
    {
        if (previous == NULL)
        {
            head = poly->next;
        }
        else
        {
            previous->next = poly->next;
        }
        struct node* tail = poly->next->next;
        poly->next->next = poly;
        poly->next = tail;
    }
    previous = poly;
    poly = poly->next;
}
```

I think that'll work. Haven't tested it.

Comment: So I have to connect poly with poly->next->next? 
I understand what you say but i don't know exactly how to do that. Do I need a previous pointer?

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou  Yes you do need a previous pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It is shown with the actual code a simple algorithm.

```
typedef struct node Node;
Node *bubbleSort(Node *head){
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)//no need sort
        return head;

    Node anchor = { 0, 0, head }, *sentinel = NULL;
    while(1){
        Node *prev = &anchor, *curr = prev->next, *next = curr->next;
        if(next == sentinel)
            break;
        while(next != sentinel){
            Node *rest = next->next;
        //  prev --> curr --> next --> rest
            if(curr->dun > next->dun){
                prev->next = next;
                next->next = curr;
                curr->next = rest;

                prev = next;
                //curr = curr;
                next = curr->next;
            } else {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                next = curr->next;
            }
        }
        sentinel = curr;
    }

    return anchor.next;
}
```